# postgres - select one specfic row of another table and store it as column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table for timeTracks with the properties startTime and stopTime that are recorded for another table called project.

With the following aggregates I managed to display the count and sum of the amount of tracks that belongs to a project. In case an active Track (one without stopTime) exists, I want 2 additional columns named "activeTrackId" and "activeTrackStartTime".

```
SLECT
count(time_track."timeTrackId") AS "timeTracksTotalCount",
floor(date_part('epoch'::text, sum(time_track."stopTime" - time_track."startTime")))::integer AS "timeTracksTotalDurationInSeconds"
activeTimeTrackId ??
activeTimeTrackStartTime ??
...
FROM project
LEFT JOIN time_track on time_track."fkProjectId" = project."projectId"
```

Technically there can be only one active track at a time. However just in case, it should only select the latest active track, if there a two tracks without stopTime.

How can I that in postgres?

Comment: Does your query have a `group by`?  Sample data and desired results would  help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation functions:

```
SELECT count(t."timeTrackId") AS "timeTracksTotalCount",
       floor(date_part('epoch'::text, sum(t."stopTime" - t."startTime")))::integer AS "timeTracksTotalDurationInSeconds"
       (array_agg(t."timeTrackId" order by t."startTime" desc) filter (where t."stopTime" is null))[1] as activeTimeTrackId,
       max(t."startTime") filter (where t."stopTime" is null) as activeTimeTrackStartTime 
...
FROM project p LEFT JOIN
     time_track t
     ON t."fkProjectId" = p."projectId"
GROUP BY ?;
```

Note that Postgres doesn't offer a `first()` aggregation function, so this uses array aggregation and then takes the first element.

If you are using an older version of Postgres, `filter` may not be available.  You can replace that with `case` expressions.

Comment: Thanks thats what I was looking for! Do I have to repeat it everytime I want to select another property? E.g. do I have to copy the entire aggregation if I wanted another coloumn for activeTimeTrackStartTime or activeTimeTrackCreatedAt?

Comment: @HanChe . . . That is the simplest method.  If you want the entire record, there are other methods that can work as well.

Comment: Would you be so kind and just point me toward the names or references of the other methods so I can look them up? The example above was just a simplifed problem of my challenge. The track table in reality is a view consiting of couple more meta information of which I also want to display as additional collumn. Hence I would prefer to aggregate and get the correct latest active track only once.

Comment: @HanChe . . . Ask another question, explaining what you want to do.  You can reference this question, so you can differentiate the answers.

Comment: Done, but I'm not sure on how accurate the title ist .. :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53996994/postgres-aggregate-information-once-and-add-add-multiple-properties-as-columns