# Postgres - aggregate information once and add add multiple properties as columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `project` and a view called `downtime_report_overview`. The `downtime_report_overview` consists of the table `downtimeReport` (`id, startTime, stopTime, downTimeCauseId, employeeId, ...`) and the joined `downtimeCause.name`.

Thanks to Gorden's reply ([postgres - select one specfic row of another table and store it as column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53996511/postgres-select-one-specfic-row-of-another-table-and-store-it-as-column)), I am able to include an active downtime (stopTime = null) via an array aggregate and filter as column to the project query. Since I might need to more properties to the downtime_report_overview (e.g. meta data like username) in the near future I was wondering if is a way where I can extract the correct downtimeReport only once.

In the example below I using the array aggregation 3 times, once id, startTime and causeName. It seems verbose on the one hand and on the other I'm not even certain that it will select the correct downTime row for all 3 columns.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(downtime_report_overview."downtimeReportId") AS "downtimeReportsTotalCount",
    FLOOR(date_part('epoch'::text, sum(downtime_report_overview."stopTime" - downtime_report_overview."startTime")))::integer AS "downtimeReportsTotalDurationInSeconds",
    (array_agg(downtime_report_overview."downtimeReportId" ORDER BY downtime_report_overview."startTime" DESC) FILTER (WHERE downtime_report_overview."stopTime" IS null))[1] AS "activeDownTimeReportId",

(array_agg(downtime_report_overview."startTime" ORDER BY downtime_report_overview."startTime" DESC) FILTER (WHERE downtime_report_overview."stopTime" IS null))[1] AS "activeDownTimeReportStartTime",

(array_agg(downtime_report_overview."downtimeCauseName" ORDER BY downtime_report_overview."startTime" DESC) FILTER (WHERE downtime_report_overview."stopTime" IS null))[1] AS "activeDownTimeReportCauseName"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to approach this.  Obviously, you can write a separate expression for each column.  Or, you can play around with manipulating an entire row as a record.

In this case, perhaps the simplest approach is to separate the aggregation and getting the row of interest.  Based on the *original* question, the code would look like:

```
SELECT p.*, tt.*
FROM (SELECT p."projectID"
             count(t."timeTrackId") as "timeTracksTotalCount",
             floor(date_part('epoch'::text, sum(t."stopTime" - t."startTime")))::integer AS "timeTracksTotalDurationInSeconds"
      FROM project p LEFT JOIN
           time_track t
           ON t."fkProjectId" = p."projectId"
      GROUP BY p."projectID"
     ) p LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT ON (t."fkProjectId") tt.*
      FROM time_track tt
      WHERE t."stopTime" is null
      ORDER BY t."fkProjectId", t."startTime" desc
     ) tt
     ON tt."fkProjectId" = p."projectId";
```